# Integrating an exponential with upper incomplete gamma functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I would greatly appreciate calculating an integral consisting of an upper incomplete gamma function and an exponential function.

```
Integrate[Exp[-L y] Gamma[t, (Sqrt[z (y + w)/a])/n], {y, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image]

I would like to find it in an exact non-numerical closed-form.

Comment: What happened when you executed the code you give?  Have  you tried `NIntegrate` with specific values of $L$, $t$, $z$, $w$, $a$, and $n$?

Comment: You should explain where this integral comes from and why it is related to `probability-or-statistics`. More details regarding constants is crucial.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Do you have good reason to believe that a closed-form solution actually exists?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2289180).

Comment: Why haven't you improved your question including suggestions above in the comments_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just an additional comment to @Artes answer.  (All the real work was provided in that answer.)

The term

```
(Sqrt[z (y + w)/a])/n
```

can be simplified without loss of generality with

```
c Sqrt[y + w]
```

So instead of 3 parameters ($z$, $a$, and $n$), you only need 1.  Doing so gets you explicit solutions for all positive integer values of $t$.  For example:

```
t = 3;
Integrate[Exp[-L y] Gamma[t, c Sqrt[y + w]], {y, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> L > 0 && w > 0 && c > 0] // FunctionExpand
```

[image: Integral for t = 3]

One might see patterns to end up with a single function for any positive integer value of $t$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Too many symbolic constants usually turn out to be obstructive to calculate integrals symbolically. Another problem comes up when no restriction for parameters is given. We can set specific values to a few constants using  `With` and (or) restrict constants with an option `Assumptions` in `Integrate` e.g.

```
With[{n = 1, a = 1, z = 1}, 
     Table[{t, Integrate[ Exp[-L y] Gamma[t, (Sqrt[z (y + w)/a])/n],
                          {y, 0, Infinity}, 
                          Assumptions -> L > 0 && w > 0]},
            {t, 4}]]
```

[image]

We could also restrict appropriately all constant but one, however then *Mathematica* cannot provide symbolic results for certain values of `t`, e.g. for `t = 3` the integral is not found

```
Table[{t, Integrate[ Exp[-L y] Gamma[t, (Sqrt[z (y + w)/a])/n],
                     {y, 0, Infinity}, 
                     Assumptions -> L > 0 && n > 0 && a > 0 && z > 0 && w > 0]},
      {t, 4}]
```

[image]

Perhaps next versions of the system should provide more general results.

Comment: Thank you very much.